# Encrypting a whole row of text

Tags: python, encryption

I am making a function to encrypt a whole row of text. I have made a function that encrypts individual letters already, but I am stuck in encrypting whole words.

Here is my code:

```
def encrypt(text):
    """
    Encrypts its parameter using ROT13 encryption technology.

    :param text: str,  string to be encrypted
    :return: str, <text> parameter encrypted using ROT13
    """

    regular_chars   = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
                       "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
                       "w", "x", "y", "z"]

    encrypted_chars = ["n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x",
                       "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i",
                       "j", "k", "l", "m"]
    if text.lower() not in regular_chars:
        return text

    index = regular_chars.index(text.lower())
    new_char = encrypted_chars[index]

    if text.isalpha():
        if text not in regular_chars:
            return new_char.upper()
        else:
            return new_char


def row_encryption(text):
    """
    Encrypts a row
    """

    for i in range (1, len(text)):
        encrypt(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `row_encryption`

```
def row_encryption(text):
    """
    Encrypts a row
    """

    for i in range (1, len(text)):
        encrypt(text)
```

has 2 serious problems. Firstly it does feed whole `text` to `encrypt` function rather than single character, secondly it does nothing with what `encrypt` return. Assuming `encrypt` work correctly then `row_encryption` might look for example as follows

```
def row_encryption(text):
    encoded = ''
    for char in text:
        encoded = encoded + encrypt(char)
    return encoded
```

Note that you might iterate over str characters using `for` loop, without need to use `range`. I also simply write to end of encoded (which is initially empty `str`) what `encrypt` function return, so I can at end return encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can encrypt a string already.
If you want to encrypt a row you could adjust your code to encrypt only letters and keep other characters ( . ! ? .. etc. ) as is.